# trying to connect database with php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a registration page and I have phpmyadmin set on xampp, my apache's port is `8080` and 
my table's name is `registration` and my database's name is `loginregister`,
whenever I submit it the values arent getting transmitted to the table and i don't see any errors, help?

this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post" name="form1">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter your first name*</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="fname" required="yes" pattern="^[a-z1-9]+"></td>
            <td><p>Username takes only small letters or numbers, no capital letters</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter your last name*</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="lname" required="yes"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter your password*</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="pw" required="yes"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter your email adress*</td>
            <td><input type="email" name="email" required="yes"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter your username*</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="uname" required="yes"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit1"></input></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
        {
        $link=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','' , "loginregister");
        $res= "INSERT INTO loginregister (fname , lname , pw , email , uname) VALUES('$_POST[$fname]','$_POST[$lname]','$_POST[$pw]','$_POST[$email]','$_POST[$uname]'))";
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't even attempt to insert anything into your database. You're literally missing almost all of the code necessary to do this. How did you think this would work?

Comment: How do I do that then? I used  `$res= mysqli_query("INSERT INTO loginregister (fname , lname , pw , email , uname) VALUES('$_POST[$fname]','$_POST[$lname]','$_POST[$pw]','$_POST[$email]','$_POST[$uname]'))";)` and put

Comment: You should read-up on sql injection before you actually try to execute that query...

Comment: Your question doesn't show the `mysqli_query`. Also you never check if your connection was established.

Comment: @moran There is no `mysqli_query` in your code example. Check your code with [mysqli_error()](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: Maybe start here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple PHP Database Connections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718260/simple-php-database-connections)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I completely forgot to explain my answer. My bad!

In your piece of code you did not post anything to your database. All you did was create a connection with `mysqli_connect`.

Here is a piece of code using PDO to save the registered user to your database, safely.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
{
    /**
     * Connect to your database.
     */
    try
    {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:dbname=loginregister;host=localhost', 'root', '');
    } catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        /**
         * Catch any exceptions in case your connection should fail.
         */
        echo 'Failed to connect: '.$e->getMessage();
        die();
    }
    /**
     * Here is where you prepare your query. 
     * This is what you did in your piece of code, but never executed.
     */
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO `registration` (`fname`, `lname`, `pw`, `email`, `uname`) VALUES (:fname, :lname, :pw, :email, :uname)');
    /**
     * Your passwords should not be stored in plain-text. Ever.
     * And as John Conde pointed out, password_hash is the better way to do this.
     */
    $password  = password_hash($_POST['pw'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    /**
     * Here we assign all variables to the query.
     */
    $stmt->bindValue(':fname', $_POST['fname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':lname', $_POST['lname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':pw', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':email', $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':uname', $_POST['uname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

    /**
     * And here is where we tell the PDO statement execute your query.
     */
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful comment John. I completely forgot to elaborate on my answer.

Comment: Now your answer is upvote worthy.

Comment: Now let's hope it's useful to moran!

Comment: Thanks! works flawlessly, tho the password in line 69 isnt defined so i guess you meant $_POST['pw']? if yes then that's what i changed it to, but it shows pw as 0 so im not sure if that's supposed to be that way

Comment: Yes indeed, the password post field had not been set.